# How do I count the items on a "grocery list" using a class?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a class that includes the ability to display the length of a list. However, I get the message 'List has 0 items' instead of the actual number.

Here is my code:

'''

```
    grocery_list = []
    class GroceryList:
        grocery_list = []
        def __init__(self):
            print('Grocery List Created')
        def add(self, item):
            self.grocery_list.append(item)
        def show(self):
    print(self.grocery_list)
        def size(self):
             print('List has {} items'.format(len(grocery_list)))


    gro_list = GroceryList()
    gro_list.add('Banana')
    gro_list.add('Cat Food')
    gro_list.show()
    gro_list.size()
```

'''

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Get rid of the global `grocery_list`, and change your `size` function to use `self.grocery_list`.

Answer (score 1):

In your question the indentation was messed up, however the problem was in method `size(self)` with `grocery_list` used instead of `self.grocery_list`.

Everything else works OK.

```py
class GroceryList:

    # declare grocery_list
    grocery_list = []

    def __init__(self):
        print('Grocery List Created')

    def add(self, item):
        self.grocery_list.append(item)

    def show(self):
        print(self.grocery_list)

    def size(self):
        # self.grocery_list was the error
        print('List has {} items'.format(len(self.grocery_list)))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    gro_list = GroceryList()
    gro_list.add('Banana')
    gro_list.add('Cat Food')
    gro_list.show()
    gro_list.size()
```

Comment: ```grocery_list``` is a **class variable** - A variable that is shared by all instances of a class. You should use **instance variable**

Comment: `grocery_list` is a `list` and therefore can be modified at will. Since I have no knowledge of the OP's ultimate objectives, my answer is close to OP's original code. The problem was a confusion between a variable declared in the `namespace` and used in the `class` and the same named variable declared in the class.

Answer (score 1):

- You have two `grocery_list` in your code. One is a global one and the other is a class variable.
- By `len(grocery_list)` You are finding the length of the `grocery_list` that is declared before the Class (global).  Since you're not adding to that list (*see your `add()` function*), it shows you `0` items.
- It should be `len(self.grocery_list)` - *means find the length of `grocery_list` (class variable).*  See the `self` before the variable name.

```
class GroceryList:
    grocery_list = []
    def __init__(self):
        print('Grocery List Created')
    def add(self, item):
        self.grocery_list.append(item)
    def show(self):
        print(self.grocery_list)
    def size(self):
        print('List has {} items'.format(len(self.grocery_list)))


gro_list = GroceryList()
gro_list.add('Banana')
gro_list.add('Cat Food')
gro_list.show()
gro_list.size()
```

```
Grocery List Created
['Banana', 'Cat Food']
List has 2 items
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get zero in your code is that you are appending to the list (grocery_list) which is an attribute of the class. But in the `size()` function you are printing the length of the global `grocery_list` in which no elements were appended (i.e it is an empty list) so you get length as '0'

Try changing your `size()` function to this -

```
def size(self):
    print('List has {} items'.format(len(self.grocery_list)))
```

Also, you can remove the `grocery_list` variable at the global level (first line), because it is useless in this code.